# htaccess: need help hiding index.php and doing a redirect without conflict?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I need to redirect a page on a client site to an outside URL. I have been using the following redirect, which works - sort of:

```
redirect 301 /durhamchapelhill http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org
```

The problem is that the resulting URL is cluttered:

> http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org/?/durhamchapelhill

I sought help on StackOverflow and got a really good redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^durhamchapelhill$ http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org [R]
```

By itself, it does an awesome job and returns a nice clean URL. Which brings up the thorny issue of hiding the index.php page.

Before all of this started I was using the following to hide index.php and it works great:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The problem is I need both (hide index.php and redirect).

Here is the combination I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^durhamchapelhill$ http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However, if I combine the two rules the redirect fails.

Is there an htaccess doctor in the house that can assist with setting this straight?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be a duplicate ... can you try this answer? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/301-redirects-appending-query-string/5218#5218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three variations to try:

```
RewriteRule ^durhamchapelhill$ http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org [R,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^durhamchapelhill http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org [R,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^durhamchapelhill(.*)$ http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: It was The last one. Thank you for the options.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it sorted.